# Add input placeholder value extracted from label

Tags: jquery, html

I have the a form generated with an application. It has the following structure for every field:

```
<div id="containermssys_lastname" class="formrowcontainer ">
        <label class="formlabel">Last Name</label>
    <div class="fieldcontainer">
        <input id="mssys_lastname" name="mssys_lastname" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have to do a script which extracts the value of every label and inserts it as a placeholder to the corresponding input fields. I have got to the following script but it won't work:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('.datafields>.formrowcontainer').each(function(){
    var label = $(this).find('.formlabel').text();
    $(this).find('input').attr('placeholder',label);
 });
});
</script>
```

Please help with what is wrong...

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ugd9bk92/1/

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You might try to debug the behaviour using `console.log()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I mixed jQuery and $ in the code, I changed everything to jQuery and it works...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('.datafields>.formrowcontainer').each(function(){
  var label = jQuery(this).find('.formlabel').text();
  jQuery(this).find('input').attr('placeholder',label);
 });
});
```